# How to return paging cache in laravel?

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, pagination

I would like to know if there is any way to page this query that I do in Laravel and store it in the cache.

I've already put `->paginate()` but it seems that the cache doesn't return in Eloquent but as an object. I checked the variable's type with `gettype()`.

this is my role. Can anyone help me?

```
public function getProductsRecommendations($keywords)
{
    $expiration = 10;
    $keyName = 'productsRecommended';

    $list = Cache::remember($keyName, $expiration, function () use ($keywords) {
        return  Product::query()->where(function ($productsAll) use ($keywords) {
            if ($keywords) {
                foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
                    $productsAll->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->orWhere('code', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');
            }
        })->where('status', 'active')->get();
    });

    return $list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cache your results per page, with a key that is the current page. Something like:

```
$currentPage = request()->get('page',1);

$category = Cache::remember('sellcategory-' . $currentPage, 10, function(){
    return DB::table('elans')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->where(['derc' => 1,'elaninnovu' => 'Satılır'])->paginate(10);
});
```

Comment: I can't keep the pagination inside the cache, because in my case the pagination can be changed. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I needed. I'll leave it here in case someone goes through the same problem and finds this question.

Sometimes you might want to create an instance of paging manually, passing in an array of items. You can do this by creating an `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` or `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` instance, depending on your needs.

To exemplify:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

$paginator = new Paginator($array, $rowPerPage, $currentPage = null);
```